# Python import conflicts

Tags: python, import, flask

I'm running into issues executing a Flask app in unit test mode. For some reason the same module gets imported twice (seems not a problem in the flask app when I run it as development server). The structure is like so:

```
  -- app
    |
    --blueprint
       |-- __init__.py : import foo; from .bar import aaa
       |-- foo.py : # some sqlalchemy model setup, etc
       |
       |-- bar
       |    | -- __init__.py : from bar import bbb
            | -- bar.py : from app.foo import ccc
```

The problem is in `bar.py` which uses function `foo.py:ccc` runs the sqlalchemy model definition twice (which fails as metadata already has the model registered). How can this conflict be avoided? I am also stunned as to why this doesn't happen if I run the flask application not as a unit test.

Comment: Avoid absolute imports inside packages. Replace `import foo` with `from . import foo`, `from bar import bbb` with `from .bar import bbb` etc. Alternatively always use `from app import foo` etc. This makes your code more portable(in python3 you'd probably get some `ImportError`). Also if you added the `blueprint` directory to the pythonpath then the mixture of imports might perform double imports as you see. By the way: try to provide a minimal working example of your problem.

Comment: I think I've used relative imports as you suggested, but the problem is that `ccc` is used in `bar.py` which requires an absolute import and that it's importing the function while its being imported. `app` is on the pythonpath, so I have to import `blueprint.bar.bbb` for instance. I try to come up with a running example and post it here.

Comment: @orange: Can you include more than just the directory structure? I'm sure your code has something to do with this as well.

Comment: While trying to construct an example, I actually managed to solve the issue. The problem was that for the test case, I was importing a function from a file that sits directly under `app`. This meant that I could import `blueprint.bar.bbb` as well as `app.manage.init` (`manage.py` is not in the above example). This didn't work well and moving `init` to one of the blueprints resolved the issue.